# Apps detecting Android on VirtualBox as jailbroken/rooted

Tags: virtualbox, rooting

I'm using Android in a VM, namely VirtualBox. The reason for this is that my bank forces me to use the (very badly rated) banking app SecureGo, but I have no Android or iOS device.

These things worked well:

- Setting up the VM
- Installing android
- Installing the SecureGo app

However, SecureGo refuses to work because it says that it detected a jailbreak or rooting on my device.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Configuration

- Virtualbox 6.1
- Android 8.1.0 (x86 64-bit iso from [fosshub.com/Android-x86-old.html](https://fosshub.com/Android-x86-old.html))

Comment: What "Android" have you instjalled - AndroidX86 or what other distribution did you choose?

Comment: I installed the x86 64-bit iso from https://www.fosshub.com/Android-x86-old.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the error message SecureGo shows is most likely not the actual reason. Banking apps and other security sensitive apps often check their environment and if something is not as they expect from a real unrooted device they simply state that the device is rooted, no matter if this is true or not.

As your device is not a genuine Google Android device at all I don't think SecureGo will ever run on it.

Therefore the only way is to speak with your bank and ask what they provide for people without smartphone and tablet. And if they don't offer your something then you have the two choices to stay and buy a cheap Android phone or switch the bank.

If you decide to stay make sure the device you buy is not from an unknown Chinese vendor. Only consider large well known brands.

Comment: I was afraid of an answer like that. Sadly, it seems that banks in Germany are currently being forced into this kind of policy by law and the ones I checked offer this app only.

Comment: @rttpik German Banks have to provide a service fir switching the bank, so switching to a different bank is easy and there are still some banks providing a free giro bank account. SMS TAN as is also a still valid second factor and some banks that use QR-code based systems provide physical readers for a small fee (~30 euro).

Comment: Thanks @Robert. As for your first comment, is there no way to make the OS believe that it is on a real phone + make the app believe that it is on a real Android OS living on a real phone? My (layperson's) understanding has been so far that this is what VMs are all about.